# How to get started with Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm having trouble understanding the workflow of webpack.

In a regular project, I would have something like this:

HTML:

```
<button onclick = "doSomething()"></button>
```

And then in javascript I'll write the function

```
function doSomething(){}
```

I understand as the project grows I need to make the javascript more modular using Webpack. But how do I make the bundled javascript interact with the HTML? For example:

entry.js (pseudo code):

```
import moduleThatDoesThings;
```

moduleThatDoesThings.js:

```
function doSomething(){}
```

This won't work:

HTML:

```
<button onclick="moduleThatDoesThings.doSomething()"></button>
```

How do I call functions from modules in the HTML? Or am I supposed to think like this at all? If not how should I structure the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React has it's own render() function where you can place your html code and interact with the components methods

Answer (score 0):

So I learned I can either use react or do element.addEventListener on each element on vanilla js.